# What might explain a query string URL 'site.php?params' becoming 'site.php_params'?

Tags: php, apache

I lately have a strange problem on my website on a webhoster. At random, site.php?params becomes site.php_params, making the site inaccessible. It's not really reproducible; it happens in different locations, at random times, after random redirects.

I do not have root though on the webserver, so I can't change anything on the Apache or PHP files itself... Although if I knew what was going on, I could contact my hoster.

- OS: Linux
- PHP Version 5.3.28
- Apache API Version: 20051115

What I would do, if I had access to the Apache files: create a rewrite rule that changes .php_ to .php? - Would that help?

Comment: It cannot be "random". That would make no sense. There must be an underlying logic for this to happen. How does your .htaccess look like?

Comment: well, I could not make any underlying logic yet, hence the question. If I knew what was going on, it would not be to hard to find a solution.
Well, that's another problem: the webhoster doesn't seem to support .htaccess for it's users.

Comment: Try to find a situation where it does happen. Otherwise it's almost impossible to help. And what do you mean by "random redirects"?

Comment: Does this happen with just one of your web apps, or any? Does it happen with any other customers on the same box? (If you don't know about the latter, ask technical support).

Comment: (If this is just one application, I expect this is a bug in your web app - please add that into your list of software in the question).